# Can I use one select statement to get multiple rows from 2 tables with FK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select * from the Players table where FriendID = PlayerID.  The catch is that 1 player can have many friends, so I could have multiple rows in the Friends table where the PlayerID is the same but the FriendID is different.  FriendID is also a FK on the PlayerID field in the Players table.

I could do this with 2 separate queries.  First I select FriendID from Friends where PlayerID = ID then I could loop through all the FriendID's returned selecting * from Players where PlayerID = FriendID.  It seems like this should be easier and is part of the point of maintaining the FK relationship?  Do I have to do this with 2 separate queries or am I missing something?

Here are the tables, in Friends FriendID is a FK on PlayerID in Players

```
[Players]
PlayerID
Name
Email
```

and

```
[Friends]
PlayerID
FriendID
```

Update:

Here is some data and expected results.

```
Friends
PlayerID = 6, FriendID = 9
PlayerID = 6, FriendID = 11

Players
PlayerID = 9, Email = bl@bl.c, Name = Pedro
PlayerID = 11, Email = ca@ca.ca, Name = Marcus
```

Result would be getting all the data listed above in the players table by querying the Friends table.  Essentially select * from Friends Where PlayerID = 6 then select * from Players where PlayerID = 9 and 11.  hope this makes a little more sense...

Comment: do you know about SQL Join clauses?

Comment: I am familiar with join clauses but am not sure how to solve my problem using them?

Comment: I am sure there is a less confusing way to ask this question :) Answer couldn't be too complex, it might need a self-join I guess. Could you use some example rows like playerA,PlayerB  and explain your expected result?

Comment: LOL, yea it is a confusing question for what seems like a really simple problem.

Comment: The schema is not properly built for doing this easily. You  should have created a third table and had a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @icemanind can you explain why you think this?  I did wonder the same thing but felt it wasn't necessary in the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for?

```
DECLARE @id int = 777

SELECT Players.*
FROM Players
JOIN Friends
ON Friends.FriendID = Players.PlayerID
WHERE Friends.PlayerID = @id
```

This should get all of the player information about all the FriendIDs associated with a PlayerID in the Friends table.

Comment: This did the trick!!  Thank you so much and sorry for the super confusing question...